# How to use KSH variable in string and Robotframework not to interpret it for a case variable

Tags: variables, robotframework

I tried to use Robot to do the following operation in KSH to remove the ".auto" postfix in a directory:

Write for file in .auto; do mv $file ${file%.}; done

The ${file%.} is for KSH variable however Robot always considered it as Robot variable and gave the error message: "Resolving variable '${file%.}' failed: Variable '${file}' not found."

Is there any way to tell Robot that the ${file%.*} is not for a Robot variable?

Comment: are you asking about [robot framework](robotframework.org)? It's not clear exactly what you mean by "robot", especially since the `robot` tag is supposed to be for physical robots.

Comment: Yes it's about [robot framework](robotframework.org)? Sorry I put the wrong tag and I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

If a string has something the framework may interpret as inline variable usage - escape it, with the `\` char.

In your case, put it in front of the `${`:

```
Write     for file in .auto; do mv $file \${file%.}; done
```